# parsing a json object created using each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

i get data named `dataFromServer` from server in this format.

```
[
{"Name":"txtFirstName","Parent":"Alpha"},
{"Name":"txtLastName","Parent":"Alpha"},
{"Name":"btnSESearch","Parent":"Alpha"},
{"Name":"tblfootblSearchPat","Parent":"Bravo"},
{"Name":"btn-action-SPG-delete","Parent":"Bravo"}
]
```

and i want to change into this format

```
{ 
"Alpha": 
[
{ "Name": "txtFirstName" }, 
{ "Name": "txtLastName" }, 
{ "Name": "btnSESearch" }, 
],
"Bravo":
[
{ "Name": "tblfootblSearchPat" }, 
{ "Name": "btn-action-SPG-delete" }, 
]
}
```

im doing this to get data in required format

```
var jsonObjLoop = '{';
var item = '"Alpha" :[';
$.each(dataFromServer, function (idx, val) {
    item += '{"Name":"' + val.NAME + '"},';
});
item += ']}';
jsonObjLoop += item;
console.log(jsonObjLoop);
```

Comment: `jsonObj["Alpha"]`

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. Please update it with your real situation. You've said *"but when i assign this string to a variable and console it then it displays correctly formatted json "* but assigning the string to a variable and console logging it is **exactly** what you do in your first example.

Comment: please add the data of `dataFromServer` and the wanted result in text form.

Comment: Side note: Don't create JSON via string concatenation. It's error-prone and unnecessary.

Comment: you can just create this as a javascript object, and then stringify it to display it. Building it up using strings is much more likely to result in bugs. Why are you making this complicated, when the language has a built-in way to do this task?

Comment: i have edited the question. hope it is clear. apologize for vague statement in the first place

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @ADyson im newbie, i searched alot on internet and came up with this solution. thanks for suggesting JavaScript object. i try for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the data array and iterate it. Then use an object for grouping and assign a new object to the group of the parent.

```js
var data = [{ Name: "txtFirstName", Parent: "Alpha" }, { Name: "txtLastName", Parent: "Alpha" }, { Name: "btnSESearch", Parent: "Alpha" }, { Name: "tblfootblSearchPat", Parent: "Bravo" }, { Name: "btn-action-SPG-delete", Parent: "Bravo" }],
    grouped = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(function (a) {
    grouped[a.Parent] = grouped[a.Parent] || []; // checks if parent exist, if not create array
    grouped[a.Parent].push({ Name: a.Name });
});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Version with variable property to group on

```js
function groupBy(array, key) {
    var grouped = Object.create(null);
    data.forEach(function (a) {
        var o = Object.create(null);
        Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
            if (k !== key) {
                o[k] = a[k];
            }
        });
        grouped[a[key]] = grouped[a[key]] || [];
        grouped[a[key]].push(o);
    });
    return grouped;
}

var data = [{ Name: "txtFirstName", Parent: "Alpha" }, { Name: "txtLastName", Parent: "Alpha" }, { Name: "btnSESearch", Parent: "Alpha" }, { Name: "tblfootblSearchPat", Parent: "Bravo" }, { Name: "btn-action-SPG-delete", Parent: "Bravo" }];

console.log(groupBy(data, 'Parent'));
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: that's the exact answer i wanted @Nina. appreciate that you understood my problem, one more thing please, can i put `Parent` in a variable and use that variable instead of using `Parent` word. like: `var groupBy = 'Parent'` and `grouped[a.groupBy]`. i tried it but it does't work :-(

Comment: @Shaybi, plaese see version 2. the new objects are now dynamic created without the grouping key.

Comment: awesome. hope i will find u next time when needed:-)

Comment: you could upvote and/or accept the answer you helped (most), please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

**Try [for in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) :**

```js
var dataFromServer = [
{"Name":"txtFirstName","Parent":"Alpha"},
{"Name":"txtLastName","Parent":"Alpha"},
{"Name":"btnSESearch","Parent":"Alpha"},
{"Name":"tblfootblSearchPat","Parent":"Bravo"},
{"Name":"btn-action-SPG-delete","Parent":"Bravo"}
];

var newObj = {};

for (var i in dataFromServer) {
  newObj[dataFromServer[i].Parent] = newObj[dataFromServer[i].Parent] || [];
  newObj[dataFromServer[i].Parent].push({ "Name": dataFromServer[i].Name});
}

console.log(newObj);
```